# Ok smeone tell me where I'm wrong here

Tags: javascript

```js
var fn = document.forms["myForm"]["first-name"].value;
var pw = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;

if (fn == "giannis" && pw == "1234"); {
    window.location.href="index.html";
} else {
    alert("Invalid username or password")
}
```

Well I have error in the word else and  I can't see why. I asked a friend who is good at JavaScript and he told me to come here

Comment: Remove the `;` after the closing `)` on your `if` condition. `if(fn=="giannis" && pw=="1234");` => `if(fn=="giannis" && pw=="1234")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(fn=="giannis" && pw=="1234");
```

Remove the semi colon.

Comment: Typo-level questions just get comments and close votes here on SO. They don't serve a useful purpose for others in the future. Please don't post answers to them, as doing so can prevent the OP from deleting the question.